# Wireless HDMI to connect Macbook Pro with Dell 22N700 monitor

Tags: hdmi, wireless

I need to connect the display of my MacBook Pro to my Dell 22N700 (22 inch) monitor, wirelessly. Currently I use an HDMI cable. Please suggest. It would be great if that device works with Windows 10 as well.

Comment: You're not goign to have any luck for a dual-OS solution. You're in the same boat as somebody looking for a [wireless projector](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2475/wireless-hd-projector-2000-lumen/2508), other than the fact that you'd need to add an external WiDi/Miracast adapter for the Windows half (instead of having it built in to the device).

Comment: @T.J.L. Ok, I can work without Windows compatibility. But what about Mac and Dell.

Answer (score 1):

**Apple TV** - [$74.50 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4A02UV1201&cm_re=apple_tv-_-1J8-000T-00001-_-Product)

You can stream your display to your monitor connected to Apple TV (through HDMI) using **[AirPlay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay)** for Apple devices with OS X 10.8 or newer. Or you can use **AirParrot 2** software to connect it to your older Mac or Windows PC.

---

**Requirements:**

1. According to [this apple site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343) if your MacBook Pro is from **early 2011 or newer**. You will need only Apple TV media player 2nd generation or newer. [Here](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/airplay-on-the-mac-the-definitive-guide--mac-31704) is really good tutorial how to connect your Mac to Apple TV.
2. If your MacBook Pro is older than **early 2011** or you need mirroring from Windows PC you will also need [AirParrot 2 software](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) it costs **$13**.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you get wireless display capability from an Apple device is via [AirPlay](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201343), which requires a 2nd Generation or later [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-tv/apple-tv) and OSX 10.8 or later. The actual connection between the Apple TV and the output device will be HDMI. Who makes the display doesn't matter.